# Return only instance ID, in Lambda using describe instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am running following script in lambda function to describe ec2 instance using tags. But in response I want only instance ID, whereas it retuns lot of info. please guide or anyother way to find out ec2 insatnce id using tags. Thanks

code is:

```
import boto3
import json
from collections import defaultdict

region = 'us-east-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    
    client = boto3.client('ec2')

    running_instances = client.describe_instances(
      Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:orgid',
            'Values': [
                'demoxx',
            ]
        },
    ],
    )

    return json.loads(json.dumps(running_instances, default=str))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get instance ids from [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) you have to iterate over `Reservations`, and then over `Instances`.

Thus, you code could be:

```
import boto3
import json
from collections import defaultdict

region = 'us-east-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    
    client = boto3.client('ec2')

    running_instances = client.describe_instances(
      Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:orgid',
            'Values': [
                'demoxx',
            ]
        },
    ],
    )
    
    instance_ids = []    
    
    for reservation in running_instances['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])

    return instance_ids
```